# Is spam more likely to be sent to info@example.com? Would I be better off using a different address?

Tags: email, spam

I think that when bots gather domain names or process a list of domain names, they create email addresses like *info@example.com* or *support@example.com*.
Does selecting something different help to prevent incoming spam email? Does it affect it at all?

I have a domain named *www.example.com* and I want to create an email address for contacting my customers. I was thinking of using *info@example.com*, but I suspect that such email addresses are very public, hence some software can produce email address based on domain names. Would it be better to create an email address with something different than *info@example.com*?

Comment: People who send spam try every single possible email address.  It costs nothing to send an email.  The likelyhood of being sent spam cannot be reduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it sounds like you're asking if a some emails are more likely to be spammed than others. I suspect that the primary source of emails for spams is bots collecting any emails you mention on your site. Therefore spam bots will pick up "support@example.com" just as often as "randomgiberish@example.com?". In any case you should rely on your spam filter to do it's job and use the more professional email.

Answer (score 6):

Totally agree with @Oleksi and to add some useful advice on how someone can post his email on his website without receiving (a lot) of spam:

1. **Modifying text**. Instead of "@" using at or [at], etc, instead of "." using dot or [dot], etc. This technique proved to be useful until some of the spam bots saw a pattern in this and now are able to match it to a perfect usable email address. Seeing this, some people adapted their emails with portions of text you have to remove from your mail (ex. me@NOSPAMdomain.com - remove NOSPAM before sending email) or adding geek riddles to replace substrings from the email string (echo "siemacsiu@domain.com" | sed s/emacs/lv/).
2. **Using pictures**. Other people, let's say more creative, posted a picture with their email, so now the spam bots need to have OCR modules in order to detect the email from the picture... which actually exist.
3. **Using encoding techniques**. Some people encode their emails, so that it's not displayed in clear text. There are a lot of [online email encoding sites](http://www.ohlone.edu/org/webcenter/emailencoding.html), but some bots are smart enough to decode your email...
4. **CAPTCHA scripts**. You can create your own or use [reCAPTCHA Mailhide](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/) which does it for your. I'm sure there are others sites... but it all depends on how smart the spam bots really are.

I'm sure there are other techniques too but I hope this helps.